# Codeigniter PHP create two different array from one

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm newbie of codeigniter and PHP.

Can I separate an array into two different arrays?
This is my `$array`:

```
   Array (
    [0] => Array
      (
         [Name] => mark
         [Surname] => mark
      )[1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => greg
            [Surname] => greg
        )
   )
```

Is it possible to create an array of `$mark` and another with `$greg`?

Comment: yes, yes it is possible. but not if you don't try

Comment: can you provide what you have tried so far so that we can guide you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the value of Name as your variable name: [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

```
foreach ($arrays as $array) {
    if (isset($array['Name'])) {
        $$array['Name'] = $array;
    }
}
print_r($mark);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use eval() if you want to set a string value and make it a variable.

```php
<?php
$arrays = array(
    array(
        'Name' => 'mark',
        'Surname' => 'mark'
    ),
    array(
        'Name' => 'greg',
        'Surname' => 'greg'
    )
);
//I'd use foreach()
foreach ($arrays as $array) { 
    eval("$".$array['Name']." = array('Name'=>'{$array['Name']}','Surname'=>'{$array['Surname']}',);");
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($mark, $greg);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: why Surname => $array['Name'] again